# What is " $ argmin \|p-z\|^2 $ "?

Tags: probability-distributions, projection

Curretly, I'm reading [Sparse and Constrained Attention for Neural Machine Translation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.08241v1). This paper describes a function `sparsemax` generating probability distributions.

I could understand algorithm of `sparsemax` according to read pseudo code in `2.2 Closed-Form Solution`. However, I can't understand the formula of " $ argmin \|p-z\|^2 $ ".

#### sparsemax definition

Full definition of `sparsemax` is following:

Let $z$ is K-dimensional vector,

$\Delta^{K-1} := \left\{ p \in \mathbb{R}^K | 1^{\top} p = 1, p \geq 0 \right\}$

in words, sum of vector elements will be 1.0.

$ {{\bf sparsemax}({\bf z}) := \underset{ p \in \Delta^{K-1} }{argmin} \|p-z\|^2 } $

In my understanding, explained algorithm generates probability distributions which is represented by  $p \in \Delta^{K-1}$.

Any suggestion is welcome.

**EDIT**

- I missed a explanation of the paper, this formula calculates Euclidean projection
- This post is similar of my question: [calculating euclidean projection values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478092/calculating-euclidean-projection-values)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my understanding, explained algorithm generates probability distributions which is represented by  $p \in \Delta^{K-1}$.

This line is correct.

### argmin

arg min（or argmin）defines following:

$\underset{x \in S}{arg\ min\ f(x)} := \{ x \in S \ |\ \forall_y \in S : f(y) \geq f(x) \}$

- $x \in S\ |\ \forall_y \in S$ defines sets such that f(y)>=f(x)
- in words, this formula represents to generate set of $x$, $f(x)$ must be minimum

### $L^2$-Norm

On the other hands, "$ { \underset{ p \in \Delta^{K-1} }{argmin} \|p-z\|^2 }$".

Especially "$\|foo\|$" defines $L^2$-Norm, so unfolded formula should be following:

\begin{aligned}
\|p-z\|^2 &= (\sqrt{(p_1-z_1)^2+(p_2-z_2)^2+\cdots +(p_n-z_n)^2})^2 \\
&= (p_1-z_1)^2+(p_2-z_2)^2+\cdots +(p_n-z_n)^2
\end{aligned}

### conclude

- sparsemax function generates a set $p$, it satisfies the condition minimizing $\|p-z\|^2$